# Cannot read property '_id' of undefined using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Following is the code which i am trying to run :-

```
        poolModel
        .find({})
        .exec(function (err, pools) {
            if(err)
                return next(new customError.Database(err.toString()));

            for(var i=0; i<pools.length; i++)
            {

                pools[i].views = 31;
                console.log(pools[i]._id);
                var pool_id = pools[i]._id;


                poolModel.findByIdAndUpdate(pool_id, pools[i], function(err, pool){
                   if(err)
                    console.log(err);
                   else
                    console.log(pool.views+'');

                });
               /* poolModel.findByIdAndUpdate(ObjectId(pools[i]._id), pools[i], function(err, pool){
                    if(err)
                        return next(new customError.Database(err.toString()));
                    console.log(pool.views);

                })*/
            }
        })
```

i have views entry in my model class as well. 
But i keep getting this error :-
[TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a full Mongoose model instance as a `findByIdAndUpdate` update parameter, and that's what you're trying to do by passing `pools[i]` into that method call.

Instead, after modifying `pools[i]`, call its [`save`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) method:

```
for(var i=0; i<pools.length; i++)
{
    pools[i].views = 31;
    pools[i].save(function(err, pool){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log(pool.views+'');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

findByIdAndUpdate() is async call, putting it inside a regular for loop won't work.  it needs to be in async loop, one of the ways it can be done is to use async.each() or async.eachSeries():

```
var async = require('async');

 :
 :

async.each(pools, function(item, callback) {
  var pool_id = item._id;
  item.views = 31;
  console.log(pool_id);
  poolModel.findByIdAndUpdate(pool_id, item, function(err, pool){
    if(err)
      console.log(err);
    else
      console.log(pool.views+'');
    callback(null);
  });
}, function(err) {
  console.log('all done');
});
```

Comment: I still get the same error [TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined]